# Avoid inheritance of style

Tags: html, css

I have a select element with class "chosen-select-no-results". This is a part of the CSS chosen. As a result of this I can select multiple values in a select menu. However, when i add this select menu inside a dialog box the select inherits properties from the dialog box and loses the properties of "chosen-select-no-results". Any way to solve this issue?
Update: This is the code:

```
<div id="dialog-2" title="Dialog Title goes here..." style="display:none">

<select data-placeholder="Empty by default" id="myCountries" name="Countries[]" multiple class="chosen-select-no-results" style="width:450px" tabindex="5">

<optgroup label="Countries">    

<option id='us'>USA</option>
<option id='ca'>Canada</option>
   .
   .
   .
</optgroup>
</select></div>
```

Comment: could you give us the way you show those elements into dialog box? and the chosen-select-no-results! With that I could help you to make the chosen css rule strongest than the dialog one :-)

Comment: Please include the current code to the question.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly specificity and not inheritance. Read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) and use the developer tools in your browser to see which rules are applied to the element (and in which order).

Comment: You should also show the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the **initial** keyword:

```
selector {
    property:initial;
}
```

Donwside: doesn't work in IE - as far as I know.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp

Comment: I tried this but now the select menu has no properties.

Answer (score 1):

From a "get it done" perspective, you can use:

```
selector{
    property: value !important;
}
```

and modern browsers will override the inheritance with the value marked !important. But you should really only use !important when you can't find a way to properly structure your CSS. Look at inheritance rules and  change the way you are specifying your CSS selectors.

Comment: It is better to create specific rule outside the chosen-one but it will work :-)

Comment: It won't work if the rule is already !important, and this has nothing to do with inheritance but with specificity.

Comment: It would help to see OPs CSS.